# ORDER BY COM GROUP BY para obter último row, sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou usando este código SQL para pegar dados, primeiro ele agrupa depois organiza pela data de nascimento dos *rows*.

```
SELECT U.id, U.born_data, U.bold 
FROM users U GROUP BY U.bold ORDER BY U.born_data DESC
```

Entretanto ele faz uma inversão, ele organiza pela data os *rows* selecionados por ele mesmo (sempre os primeiros), mas eu quero que ele pegue os últimos *rows* de cada agrupamento de acordo com a data e depois de pegar todos fazer uma organização novamente pela data, sempre da data mais recente para a mais distante.

Vejam um "exemplo"

Tabela: users

```
id | bold | born_data 
----------------------
1  | BR   | 20/06/2015
2  | BR   | 22/06/2015
3  | EN   | 01/07/2015
```

Ele deve me retornar dois agrupamentos, BR e EN porém ele vai pegar de acordo com a data mais recente de cada agrupamento e depois de todos ou seja ele vai me mostrar isto:

```
COUNT | bold | born_data
------------------------
(1)   | EN   | 01/07/2015  -> A DATA MAIS RECENTE DESSE AGRUPAMENTO é tambem a mais recente de todos os agrupamentos ou seja ela vem primeiro..
(2)   | BR   | 22/06/2015 -> A DATA MAIS RECENTE DESTE AGRUPAMENTO
```

vale ressaltar que todos os dados devem ser do último row, como descrito neste problema que encontrei na resposta do Maicon.

> " Opa, vou reviver aqui por que obtive um problema que percebi apenas
>   agora, a função MAX funciona perfeitamente mostrando a data do mais
>   recente, porém ela mostra apenas a data do mais recente, eu desejo que
>   ela mostre todas as informações do mais recente. Analise este,
>   sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22c35a/2 veja que o ids nao é do mais recente."

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do output que desejas obter? Não está muito claro na tua pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Experimenta utilizando o `MAX` na data:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.bold) as COUNT, 
       MAX(U.born_data) as born_data, 
       U.bold 
FROM users U 
GROUP BY U.bold 
ORDER BY U.born_data DESC
```

Saída

```
COUNT   born_data               bold
1       July, 01 2015 00:00:00  EN
2       June, 22 2015 00:00:00  BR
```

### [SqlFiddle Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ab89/3/0)

Comment: Que legal, essa função MAX é usada apenas pra isto?

Comment: A função `MAX` é pra pegar sempre o maior valor, no caso de datas é a mais recente, existe também a função `MIN` que faz exatamente o contrário.

Comment: Opa, vou reviver aqui por que obtive um problema que percebi apenas agora, a função `MAX` funciona perfeitamente mostrando a data do mais recente, porém ela mostra apenas a data do mais recente, eu desejo que ela mostre **todas** as informações do mais recente. Analise este, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22c35a/2 veja que o `ids` nao é do mais recente.

Answer (score 0):

Em resposta à actualização da pergunta:

Tenta assim para obter o ID correspondente à data mais recente.

```
SELECT MaxData.bold_count AS COUNT, 
       U.ids, 
       MaxData.born_data, 
       MaxData.bold 
FROM users U 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT bold,
           COUNT(bold) as bold_count, 
           max(born_data) born_data
    FROM users
    GROUP BY bold
) MaxData
   ON MaxData.bold = U.bold
  AND MaxData.born_data = U.born_data 
ORDER BY MaxData.born_data DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22c35a/5)